# Xcode constraint and size classes for iphone 6 plus and up

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I wonder if there is any way to only target iphone 6 plus and up when it comes to size classes and constraints.

Looking at this:
[image]

I can't see it.

I have a UIview with a spacing of 20pt on all sides. The UIView works as a container for a search form. The UIView appears the same on all devices. But when it comes to Iphone 6 and up, the View appears to have some dead space in the bottom of the view. What I would like to do is to have a even space between all form items so that they take up the whole view.

So is there any way to target iphone 6 and up? Eg making buttons bigger / adding more space between items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to constraint the height of the buttons/fields to this UIView, so they always take for example 1/10 of its height. On the storyboard right-click drag from a control to its superview and select Height to create a constraint. Find this constraint and change it's `multiplier` from 1 to for example 1/10. This is the way I did it and I found it way less time consuming than playing around with freeform sizes and other size classes.